# Erro ao sincronizar: Could not reserve enough space for 1048576KB object heap

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Aparece esse erro quando tento sincronizar meu projeto no Android Studio, como resolver isso?

> Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
>   This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
>   For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
>   Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at   >http://gradle.org/docs/2.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
>   Please read the following process output to find out more:
>
> ---
>
> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   Could not reserve enough space for 1048576KB object heap
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

Comment: Boa noite Carlos, não entendi o "faliu" no título, acredito que fosse outra palavra que quisesse usar, faça títulos mais intuitivos, leia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error - No momento eu já editei, veja como ficou.

Comment: Boa noite, gostaria de saber se a resposta lhe ajudou? Se não, informe poderia informar se o problema persiste mesmo depois de tentar?

Answer (score 1):

Pela mensagem de erro me parece que o espaço reservado foi excedido e a seguinte mensagem:

> Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

Significa que não da mais suporte para `MaxPermSize` na versão (que provavelmente é a sua versão do JDK/Java).

Esta resposta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32365351/1518921) e [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22634689/1518921), da uma boa noção de como resolver.

`MaxPermSize` definia o tamanho máximo gerado permanente em bytes, no entanto ela foi descontinuada no JDK 8 e foi substituída por `MaxMetaspaceSize`

## Conforme o [guia de compatibilidade](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html):

> Setor: HotSpot / gc
>
> - Descrição
>
>   A linha de comando PermSize e MaxPermSize foram removidos e são ignorados. Se usado um destes comandos um alerta irá emitido para cada um deles:
>
>   ```
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=32m; support was removed in 8.0
>
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
>   ```